# How do I solve "Reached the maximum number of URI tags for http.client.requests" warning?

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I receive this warning on my app. I am reading `rfidtags` from about 30 readers at the same time.  Each time a tag comes in I am hitting the database to see if it's in there. I have a REST API that I am using.  So I use a REST template to hit the REST API.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks!

---

Here's some of my code:

```
private void vehicleRequests(List<Maybevehicle> vehicles) {
    // process list of unique tags to see if they are in the database and linked to a vehicle
    List<Maybevehicle> foundMaybeVehs = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Maybevehicle> notFound = new ArrayList<>();
    if (!vehicles.isEmpty()) {
        for (Maybevehicle v : vehicles) {
            Future<Maybevehicle> r = aService.batchVehTags(v);
            try {
                Maybevehicle m = r.get(2000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                if (r.isDone()) {
                    if (!(m.getB().getVin().equals("notindb"))) {
                        foundMaybeVehs.add(m);
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
                
            }
            
            if (!foundMaybeVehs.isEmpty()) {
                addLocation(foundMaybeVehs);
            }
        } else {
            log.info("no vehicles to check.");
        }
        
}

@Override
public Future<Maybevehicle> batchVehTags(Maybevehicle v) {
    Future<Maybevehicle> future = null;
    try {
        SimpleTaskMaybeveh task = new SimpleTaskMaybeveh(v, appRestTemplate);
        future=dbService.submit(task);
                
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
            
    return future;
}
```

```
public class SimpleTaskMaybeveh implements Callable<Maybevehicle> {
    
    private RestTemplate appRestTemplate;
    private Maybevehicle veh;
    
    public SimpleTaskMaybeveh(Maybevehicle veh, RestTemplate appRestTemplate) {
        this.veh = veh;
        this.appRestTemplate=appRestTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public Maybevehicle call() {
      String url="http://url/"+veh.getB().getRfidtag();
        String authString = "";
        byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")));
        String authHeader = "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        headers.set("Authorization", authHeader);

        HttpEntity<Bmwvehiclemain> requestEntity = new HttpEntity <Bmwvehiclemain>(headers);
        ResponseEntity<Bmwvehiclemain> results = appRestTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, Bmwvehiclemain.class);
        try {
            Bmwvehiclemain n = results.getBody();
            Maybevehicle d = new Maybevehicle(n,veh.getNewtaglocation());
            return d;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Maybevehicle notveh = new Maybevehicle("notindb");
            return notveh;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what tom solved without code? show the code and explain the problem

Answer (score 26):

So, the Spring application collects metrics on all inbound and outbound API calls. These metrics may be queried to see how many times a certain URL has been called.

In your `public Maybevehicle call()` method, you are building the url by appending to a String. This will put every URL with a unique rfidtag in its own URI tag bucket.

In order to avoid this problem, you can use a uriVariables map:

```
String url = “http://url/{rfidtag}”;
Map<String, ?> uriVariables = new HashMap<>();
uriVariables.put(“rfidtag”, veh.getB().getRfidtag();
…
ResponseEntity<Bmwvehiclemain> results = appRestTemplate
        .exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, Bmwvehiclemain.class, uriVariables);
```

This lets Spring collect metrics on `http://url/{rfidtag}` instead of having a URI tag for `http://url/rfidtag1`, `http://url/rfidtag2`, `http://url/rfidtag3`, and so forth.

This should reduce the number of URI tags your application is creating.

The default value for the maximum number of URI tags is 100. If you want metrics on more than that, you can customize it by setting its property value to something else. For example, my Spring application is configured with my `projectname-ws/src/main/resources/config/application.yml` file. In this file I could put something like

```
management:
  metrics:
    web:
      client:
        max-uri-tags: 200
      server:
        max-uri-tags: 200
```

to increase the maximum number of URI tags used for metrics.

If you simply don’t want the `Reached the maximum number of URI tags for http.client.requests` warning, you can put

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = HttpClientMetricsAutoConfiguration.class)
```

at the top of whatever class you run your application from which will rid you of the warning message but probably not resolve the underlying issue.

Comment: In my case making use of the URI vars didn't solve my problem, because it was in fact /receiving/ requests that was the issue. By (also) excluding WebMvcMetricsAutoConfiguration.class, I finally got rid of the warning!

Comment: Do you know if using a `URI`, when invoking the `RestTemplate`, would have the same effect?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed this warning is about HTTP requests that concatenate variable data to the URL instead of using variables.
And, as Paul explained, you should replace URL concatenation with parametric URLs.
Another way, using the "fluent style", to achieve this using web-client is:

```java
webClient
   .method(HttpMethod.GET)
   .uri("/.../...s/{id}/overview", id)
   .retrieve()
```

However, please note that ignoring such warning has its implications...

For example, if you are using Prometheus to scrape metrics from your app, using such concatenated URLs results with huge number of metrics such as `http_client_requests_seconds_count{clientName="...",environment="",method="GET",outcome="SUCCESS",region="",service_name="",status="200",uri="/api/.../1234-5678-90/...",}` (because spring cannot tell that two such requests that only differ in the "id" are actually the same).

So, in addition to spamming your Prometheus, such metrics are mostly useless.

In my case, my app was using a library that in turn is using web-client and is concatenating URLs.

I was looking for a way to identify these calls so I can ask them to be fixed.
Eventually I found I could use the `actuator/prometheus` endpoint to see all the web-client metrics which indeed was huge because of this issue.